# jQuery extendable function to filter "case-insensitive"

Tags: javascript, jquery

After search in `jQuery` functions I found `.Contains()` but it's not help me
I want make new function that can filter case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy!

```
jQuery.expr[':'].iContains = (a, b, c) => jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(c[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
```

Comment: How can i use this function ?!

Comment: You can use it inside selectors for example `$('div:iContains('text')').show();`